# Why doesn't this arithemtic operation work in java?

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

I was interested to see a weird error when performing the following:

```
int width = 300;
int var1 = width/3;
int var2 = width * 1/3;
int var3 = width * 2/3;
int var4 = width*(1/3);
int var5 = width * (int)(1/3);
int var6 = (int)(width*(1/3));

System.out.println("Var1: " + var1);
System.out.println("Var2: " + var2);
System.out.println("Var3: " + var3);
System.out.println("Var4: " + var4);
System.out.println("Var5: " + var5);
System.out.println("Var6: " + var6);
```

Output is this:

```
Var1: 100
Var2: 100
Var3: 200
Var4: 0
Var5: 0
Var6: 0
```

Why do the last three operations return `0`?  The parenthesis around the `1/3` seems to change something with how it performs the calculation, but even trying to case it into an `int` did not change the output.

I'm using the `BlueJ IDE` and `Java version 1.7.0_17`

---

**EDIT**

I found the answer.  It's due to the order of operation.  The `parens` cause the division to occur first, and with an `int` 1/3 or 2/3 will always equal `0`.  If I allow the `width * 2` to occur before dividing by `3` everything is OK because the number is larger than `1`.

Sometimes it's just basic math...  :)

Comment: just try printing `1/3` as an int and you will see why.

Comment: It's not the order that matters as much as the _semantics_ of the `/` operator in Java. If a division is applied between two integers the result is an integer, possibly truncating values. That's why `1/3 == 0` and `1/3.0 ~= 0.3333333`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relevant, so see [Order of Precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) as well.

Answer (score 3):

For the fourth case try this, notice that by adding a decimal point we're forcing a decimal division, not an integer division as it was before:

```
int var4 = width*(1/3.0);
```

For the last two cases, try this instead - although this ends up being equivalent to other cases before!

```
int var5 = width * (1/3);
int var6 = (width*(1/3));
```

Notice that `(int)1/3` is `0`, the cast is making the division return `0`, and `0` times anything will return ... well, `0`. There's no way those two cases are going to work if you leave the cast in place.

Comment: Which option are you referring to?  The one where I cast the whole operation as an `int`?  Why do `var1`, `var2` & `var3` work and the others do not?  Order of operation?

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? I cleaned up my explanation, I believe is fine now.

Comment: I didnt down vote you.  The issue is due to the order of operation, you are correct that 1/3 as an in will be zero, the first 3 test above work because the multiplication occurs before the division and the answer is always greater than 1.  If I try to perform the division first the answer will always be zero.  I feel like an idiot because I knew this and just didn't think it through and thought I could cast away the issue.  Whoops.  Appreciate the answer.